# are new snapshots that are being created using elastifox are public ?

Tags: amazon-ec2, privacy

I use elastifox firefox plugin to create instances and snapshots of volumes that I created.

in 'volumes and snapshots' tab in the bottom table i can filter the snapshots that I see by 'My snapshots' and 'no filter'.

does it mean that people can use that snapshots that I create as well!!!!?? if it is true can I create private snapshots somehow ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshots that you create are private by default. You must explicitly make them public if you wish to do so. You can verify the current state (private/public/shared) of any of your snapshots, by logging into the [AWS Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home#s=Snapshots), and under EC2 > Snapshots, right clicking the snapshot in question and selecting permissions.

Your snapshots should be set to 'Private' - if for some reason they are not you can easily change them there.